# How to translate ARM compiler commands to gcc cross compile toolchain?

Tags: gcc, arm, gnu-make

I have a number of armcc commands, which I like to translate to gcc options. The code was originally for a different environment. I did look at gcc --help and I did not see the same options such as --cpu. Can anyone help please? Here are the commands:

```
del .\obj\*.o

armcc  -c --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp -O1 -o ./obj/foo     ./src/foo.c
armcc  -c --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp -O1 -o ./obj/bar ./src/bar.c 

armasm    --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp     -o ./obj/buz.o  ./src/buz.s
armasm    --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp     -o ./obj/58

armlink   --scatter=scatter_foo.txt --entry=fooStart -o foo.axf ./obj/foo  ./obj/bar ./obj/buz.o ./obj/58

fromelf --bin -o foo.bin foo.axf

del .\obj\*.o

armcc  -c --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp -I ./headers/ -O1 -o ./obj/foo.o     ./src/foo.c
armcc  -c --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp -I ./headers/ -O1 -o ./obj/bar.o ./src/bar.c
armcc  -c --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp -I ./headers/ -O1 -o ./obj/buz.o      ./src/buz.c

armasm    --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp                        -o ./obj/bar.o  ./src/bar.s
armasm    --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp --diag_suppress=A1786W -o ./obj/bar.o         ./src/bar.s
armasm    --debug --cpu=Cortex-A9.no_neon.no_vfp                        -o ./obj/58

armlink   --scatter=foo.txtt  -o example.axf --entry=bar --keep=bar.o(NORMAL_IMAGE) ./obj/foo.o  ./obj/bar.o ./obj/startup.o ./obj/58
```

Comment: The options you get with `gcc --help` doesn't list all options (there are simply to many). Instead [read the online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) which should list all options. Also, the assembler and linker and object dumper (to create binary files from ELF files) is not part of GCC but of the [GNU binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/) package.

Comment: Thanks. On a slightly different note, I can not check your reply as answer. What to do? i.e. I like to, but for some reason I do not see the option on the web interface.

Comment: @user336293 Joachim Pileborg needs to copy that as an answer, not a comment. If this doesn't happen in a reasonable amount of time, perhaps you can copy that as an answer and the check the check mark underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you get with gcc --help doesn't list all options (there are simply to many). Instead read the online documentation which should list all options. Also, the assembler and linker and object dumper (to create binary files from ELF files) is not part of GCC but of the GNU binutils package. – From Joachim Pileborg