# How to translate armasm options or switches to NDK

Tags: assembly, android-ndk, arm

I have a sample that is written in armasm syntax and I like to translate it so it would compile with NDK. And I do not know what syntax NDK uses. I am told it may be GAS. I like to validate this so I can learn a little about both syntax and see how I can translate one to the other. So any comment on what are the differences between my desired syntax and what I have is greatly appreciated. How do I call the appropriate C libraries to call ARM code from my C files, and which switches do I pass to the compiler please.

Comment: This is basically the same thing as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31262164/3156750). The NDK uses a GCC-based toolchain, which means yes, you need to start reading the [binutils documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/).

Comment: Yes. I meant to focus more on any differences between ndk vs. gcc. I take it there are none, and ndk-build script should be able to accept all the switches aka options gcc accepts.

Comment: _"and ndk-build script should be able to accept all the switches aka options gcc accepts"_ Well, typically you'd specify compiler/assembler flags inside the makefile (e.g. `Android.mk`).